# How can I install a package in kile (windows)?

Tags: packages, windows, kile

I want to use the package `algorithm2e.sty` to write the code of my thesis. When I use the line `\usepackage[english]{algorithm2e}`. 
I get an error saying `ifoddpage.sty not found \RequirePackage`.

I looked in the options of Kile and I didn't find the solution. I looked on the internet and I only found some answers about Miktex and one for Kile on UBUNTU from 10 years ago.

Comment: You don't install packages in kile. You install them in your latex. Kile has nothing to do with package management. If you're using miktex then use the miktex console to install what ever you need

Comment: Kile is only a text editor, has nothing to do with Latex packages. MikTeX is mostly used in Windows, but seems that you are using KDE that are mostly used in Linux, so probably you are using also TexLive. You should know how is installed your LaTeX distribution  (MiTeX, TexLive vanilla, debian packages, other?) and  install the package accordingly (tlmgr, apt-get, etc.)